# Can "quarry" mean "notebook"?

Tags: meaning

I am looking for this definition because of the book *Quarry for Middlemarch*, which my lit professor said was George Eliot's notebook for all her research for her novel, but all of the definitions I have found so far don't really talk about quarry meaning anything like notebook.

Comment: It's just the name of the notebook she kept. A Google search suggests that there is no connection between the word "quarry" and the word "notebook". Your research suggests as much. I suggest that you accept that inference as valid.

Comment: I'm guessing that Quarry might hail from Enquiries or something similar. The other meaning of Quarry is a "sustained effort". Both of yesteryear usage.

Comment: @Chris Enquiries is not of yesteryear usage. Are you not acquainted with that renowned periodical (tabloid?) *The National Enquirer*? "Enquiring minds want to know!" is their motto. I up voted both answers though, as I don't believe that the quarry in question here pertains to "enquiries", nor "sustained effort".

Comment: Thesaurus entry for quarry: aim, chase, game, objective, prey, prize, quest, ravin, victim. I suggest chase for Middlemarch being appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

Quarry doesn't mean notebook - it means the place you go to dig out useful rocks/minerals.

So "Quarry for Middlemarch" is where all the building material to write the novel came from

Answer (score 5):

From Merriam-Webster:

> quarry *(n)*:
>   1: an open excavation usually for obtaining building stone, slate, or
>   limestone
>   2: a rich source

I suspect Ms Evans was using the second meaning.

Although it is odd, in my opinion, to refer to any collection you put together *yourself* as a "quarry"; quarries are naturally occurring sources.  Maybe she was make a weak pun with "quarto", which refers to paper of a particular size (usually about 286 by 222 mm, close to 8.5"x11").

Comment: She wrote as George Eliot, so that's a good enough name for us now. Anyway, I doubt *she* called "it" that ("it" was probably a ragbag of jottings on various sheets of paper and notepads anyway). I think that was just the name assigned by one [Anna Theresa Kitchel](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s?_encoding=UTF8&field-author=Anna%20Theresa%3B%20Kitchel&search-alias=books-uk), who's published various other stuff on Eliot.